# CXF: Programatically adding a new service to server

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I want to add a new resource to a server which is already running in CXF. I am using the example from [The CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAX-RSendpointsprogrammaticallywithoutSpring) to configure a Service without spring or any other external additions.

I'll paste the code here for future reference:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new 
JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(CustomerService.class);
sf.setResourceProvider(CustomerService.class, new SingletonResourceProvider(new 
CustomerService()));
sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/");
BindingFactoryManager manager = 
sf.getBus().getExtension(BindingFactoryManager.class);
JAXRSBindingFactory factory = new JAXRSBindingFactory();
factory.setBus(sf.getBus());
manager.registerBindingFactory(JAXRSBindingFactory.JAXRS_BINDING_ID, factory);
Server server = sf.create();
```

Now i want to add a second service to the Server i just created. My current strategy is to stop the server and rebuild it with the second class, but that means that the server is down while i add the new service.

Is there a way to add a new service directly to an existing server, without rebuilding the whole thing?

Comment: In this case OSGi might be an option for you.

Comment: Yes i am actually attempting to do this through CXF. The question is still valid. If i try to add a second server with a different resource class, I get an error saying that i cannot start a new server on the same path.